# format php query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$list_summoners = $con->query("SELECT * FROM verified_users WHERE Username='" . $search_user . "'");
```

and I was wondering how I could format it, like:

```
$list_summoners = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM verified_users WHERE Username='" . $search_user . "'");
    echo '<table align="center" style="text-align:center;"><tr><th>User</th><th>Summoner ID</th><th>Summoner Region</th><th>View Summoner</th></tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list_summoners)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['username'] . '</td><td>' . $row['summoner_id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['summoner_region'] .    '</td><td><a href="action.php?do=view_summoner&zone=c&summoner_id=' . $row['summoner_id'] . '&summoner_region=' . $row['summoner_region'] . '"><span class="button color_dark">View</span></a></td></tr>';  
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

I am asking this, because I know mysqli_query is open to abuse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you need to know [how to prevent SQL injection with `mysqli_query()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I'm asking how to do a while event for the array `$list_summoners` using `$con->query` rather than `mysqli_query`

Comment: Oh.  `$con->query()` and `mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT...')` are _equivalent_.  They are just two methods of performing exactly the same action, the first using an object-oriented style mysqli, the second using procedural style. There is _no difference_ between them in terms of functionality or security. They're both equally insecure in the context you've used them - solvable using [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead, as described in the linked question.

Comment: To loop with the first method, you would use `while ($row = $list_summoners->fetch_array())` as `$list_summoners` is a mysqli result object.

Comment: Reply as an answer, if you want I'll mark it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT...')` called in procedural mode, vs `$con->query('SELECT...')` called in object-oriented mode perform *exactly* the same function.  In both modes, `$con` is the same object - a `mysqli` connection object, but the MySQLi API offers two methods of interacting with it.

So, the use of `mysqli_query()` and `$con->query()` are *both* equally insecure when used the way you are using them, concatenating in a variable `$search_user`.  The secure method would be to avoid `mysqli_query()` entirely and instead [use a prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM verified_users WHERE Username = ?');
if ($stmt) {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $search_user);
  $stmt->execute();
  // Then bind & fetch()...
}
else echo $con->error;
```

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more details & examples on executing and fetching from the prepared statement.

Using `$con->query()` as you are, to fetch rows with a `while` loop you may call `$list_summoners->fetch_array()` as it is an object of [class `mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

```
if ($list_summoners) {
  while ($row = $list_summoners->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<table align="center" style="text-align:center;"><tr><th>User</th><th>Summoner ID</th><th>Summoner Region</th><th>View Summoner</th></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . '</td><td>' . htmlspecialchars($row['summoner_id']) . '</td><td>' .  htmlspecialchars($row['summoner_region']) .    '</td><td><a href="action.php?do=view_summoner&zone=c&summoner_id=' . htmlspecialchars($row['summoner_id']) . '&summoner_region=' . htmlspecialchars($row['summoner_region']) . '"><span class="button color_dark">View</span></a></td></tr>';  
    echo '</table>';
  }
}
```

Note the addition of `htmlspecialchars()` to those values, when sent to output as HTML. Even if these were not originated from user input, it is an important habit to be in as it will prevent cross-site scripting when outputting values originating from user input, or values which contain characters requiring entity encoding in HTML.